# I want to learn codeigniter, please post a link to download ebook for beginners

Tags: codeigniter, pdf

I want to learn codeigniter, please post a link to download ebook(pdf) for beginners.

Comment: This is not about PDF and shouldn't be marked as such. It isn't even a programming question so it shouldn't be asked here in the first place. Finally, Google is your friend.

Comment: You can simply reply, why you are giving me -1. If you do not want to answer then don't reply. You should not give -1 to this question.

Comment: I'm giving you -1 because your question is not correct for this forum and because you're wasting the time of those people who answer questions here. I don't want to be rude, but StackOverflow is such a great resource exactly because it is kept clean and because off-topic questions are closed quickly. Finally, I didn't answer because your question is about code igniter which I don't know. I only read it because your question is also (incorrectly) tagged with "PDF". Don't shoot the messenger, learn from what is said.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Following are some important links or you can google it

1. https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/
2. http://tutorialcodeigniter.com/
3. http://www.ccr.ro/files/products/codeigniter-1.7-professional-development_1.pdf